# List Item aligninment issue with Recycler View

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-recyclerview, listitem

One of my project i used [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) to show the list of items to the user and it is working like a charm. Now as a try i replaced the Listview with the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and succeed to show the items to the user.

Well the problem is when ever i used a customized  Listview item it is working with the Listview. But when i try to load the same with RecyclerView it is not aligning/ fitting for the screen.

Here is my expected result.. I achieved this by using ListView.. Here is the Result what i am expecting

[image]

but when i used RecyclerView it is showing as below.

[image]

But i am using the same listview_item xml for both views to load..

Here is my listview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:weightSum="9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/green" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_followupone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/nored" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_followuptwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/yesgreen" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/finalise" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static ArrayList<SearchParms> itemData;
    private static Context abc;
    private int durationOfPatientRecord;

    View itemLayoutView;

    public MyAdapter( ArrayList<SearchParms> items, Context context) {
        this.itemData = items;
        this.abc=context;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row_serch, null);


        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

        SearchParms item = itemData.get( position );


        viewHolder.textView1.setText( item.getPartcipantId());
        viewHolder.textView2.setText( item.getParticipantName());
        viewHolder.textView3.setText( "" + item.getAge());
        viewHolder.textView4.setText( item.getCreateDate());
                                   viewHolder.imgView1.setImageResource( R.drawable.finalise );
        viewHolder.imgView2.setImageResource( R.drawable.yesgreen );
                      viewHolder.imgView3.setImageResource( R.drawable.yesgreen );
        itemLayoutView.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( "#15ffffff" ) );


        }

    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView 
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

        public TextView textView1, textView2,textView3, textView4, textView5;
        public ImageView imgView1, imgView2, imgView3, imgView4;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            textView1 = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView2 = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView3 = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textView4 = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            textView5 = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

            imgView1 = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imgView2 = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_followupone);
            imgView3 = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_followuptwo);
            imgView4 = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i=getAdapterPosition();

            SearchParms item = itemData.get( i );

            Toast.makeText(abc, "You Selected::   " +item.getParticipantName(), 3000).show();

        }
    }

    // Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemData.size();
    }
}
```

where it is making problem. is there any type of limitation for using RecyclerView? Curious to know about this. Thanks

Comment: can you post your RecyclerView xml

Comment: i think there is issue with your adapter

Comment: i updated my adapter class also @Nilesh

Comment: @Gangulian i know it's not the solution, but i recommend that you don't use the weight for the list items. It is very bad in performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of setting your view like this:

```
itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.list_row_serch, null);
```

Do the following:

```
itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.list_row_serch, parent, false);
```